# webjars-play: How to use WebJarsUtil in Play 2.7

Tags: scala, playframework, webjars, twirl

After migrating to Play `2.7.0-RC3` I get the following Compile Exception:

`value css is not a member of org.webjars.play.WebJarsUtil`

I use this in the Twirl-Template like:

```
// inject
@this(webJarsUtil: org.webjars.play.WebJarsUtil)
...
@Html(webJarsUtil.css("dataTables.semanticui.min.css"))
...
```

How do I have to use this with Play 2.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking the [Unit test](https://github.com/webjars/webjars-play/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/webjars/play/WebJarsUtilSpec.scala), I figured it out:

```
// inject
@this(webJarsUtil: org.webjars.play.WebJarsUtil)
...
@webJarsUtil.locate("dataTables.semanticui.min.css").css()
...
```

This also worked for the scripts:

```
@webJarsUtil.locate("jquery.dataTables.min.js").script()
```